# Json Array as response to android client

Tags: java, json, gson

i have a requirement in which the json array response should look like this

**[{"rank":231,"title":"The Night of the Hunter"},{"rank":232,"title":"Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl"},{"rank":233,"title":"Lagaan: Once Upon a Time in India"},{"rank":234,"title":"Castle in the Sky"}]**

---

this response it received by the android client n it parses accordingly, somehow i have not been able to generate the correct response structure.

I would appreciate help a lot ryt now

```
@WebServlet("/JsonHost")
public class JsonHost extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int rank;
    int title;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // get request parameters for userID and password

        String[] movie = {
                "The Shawshank Redemption",
                "The Godfather",
                "The Godfather: Part II",
                "The Dark Knight",
                "Pulp Fiction",
                "Schindler's List",
                "12 Angry Men"..............};


int offset=0;
    int limit=20;

        if (request.getParameter("offset") != null)
            offset = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("offset"));
        System.out.println("offset value:" + offset);


        JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(movie));

    //  System.out.println(gn.toJson(mJSONArray));

        //out.println(gn.toJson(mJSONArray));

        String m[][] = new String[20][20];

        for (int rank = 0; rank < offset + limit && rank < movie.length; rank++){
                for (int title = 0; title < offset+limit; title++) {

                    m[rank][title] = movie[title];



                //  System.out.println(m[rank][title]);
                    out.println(gn.toJson(m[rank][title]));
                }

            }


        }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: What you tried please share

Comment: google about `Gson` and `jackson`

Comment: i have tried that m using Gson just that i m confused as to how generate the correct structure, i have edited to include some codes please check @NinadPingale

Comment: @Lrrr m using Gson but the structure wont come correct, something wrong the way m implementing it i guess please check

Comment: sorry its an object to Gson class i must hv left it out while editing @Lrrr

Comment: @sapamlucy check out my answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use **Gson** you could do this:

1. create a class for your movies like this :

   ```
   public class Movie {

              private int rank;
       private String name;

       public Movie(int rank, String name) {
           this.rank = rank;
           this.name = name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setRank(int rank) {
           this.rank = rank;
       }

       public int getRank() {
           return rank;
       }
   }
   ```
2. have a List of your movies like :

   ```
   List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
   ```
3. add some movies to your list:

   ```
   movies.add(new Movie(1,"The Shawshank Redemption"));
   movies.add(new Movie(2,"The Godfather"));
   ```
4. convert your list to Json :

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();

   String movieJsonList = gson.toJson(movies);
   ```

you could see that the String `movieJsonList` will be :

**[{"rank":1,"name":"The Shawshank Redemption"},{"rank":2,"name":"The Godfather"}]**

Comment: thank u it was so simple but i guess i needed u to show me the way

Answer (score 1):

Here is your task.I hope it will help you.!

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    int index=0;
    for(int i=231;i<235;i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("rank", i);
        jsonObject.put("title", movie[index++]);
        array.put(jsonObject);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i learnt something though it is not what i was looking for